# Durandaljs 2.0 Global javascript variables and dependency javascript libraries

Tags: javascript, requirejs, single-page-application, durandal

I would like to know how you can specify global javascript variables, I know you can reference these in the main index file, but can this be done cleaner?

Also if I want to use a datetimepicker javascript library that needs another library, i need to define the 2 libraries to use one of them, can this be done another way, like if I use the datetimepicker javascript library the other ons is also loaded in memory?

Thanks! :)
Bert

Answer (score 1):

Just create a module named something like session and require it from your different modules.  You can store any variables there and reference them with session.whatever.